# How to store words into an array/arraylist without having duplicate words

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, file-io

For this program i'm making I need to read in sentences ex.(Tom is fast) from a txt file and store the words into an array/list. Where I'm stuck is being able to not duplicate words and also create arrays for the words position in the array, the position of the words in each sentence, and  total number of words. Once I have the arrays completed I must have the user ask which sentence they'd like to see and print it out for them.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class CSC240_Week1MsgMapping
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter name of a file");
      String filename = kb.nextLine();
      File file = new File(filename);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
      ArrayList<String> msgs = new ArrayList<String>();

      while(inputFile.hasNext())
      {
         msgs.add(inputFile.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

When I'm trying not to duplicate objects in a List I always use a `HashMap` because for one it has the `contains(Object ob)` method which returns `true` if the `HashMap` already has the object `ob` which will be useful in your situation.

In your case I suggest that you use a `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>` the `String` would be a certain word and the `ArrayList<Integer>` would be a list of all positions of this word.

Also before Inserting a word you would check if it's already in your `HashMap` by using the `map.contains(word)` method, if the word exists you would simply add the position to the `ArrayList` realtive to that word `map.get(word).add(position)`, if the word doesn't exists that means you need to add the word to tha `HashMap` and then proceed to adding its position.

Finally, to get the count of a certain word you would simply use the `size()` method of the `ArrayList` (ex: `map.get(word).size()`).